# Proper way to download multiple AWS s3 files via javascript and zip

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have multiple images. I want to download the files in the client side and zip it. I tried using JSZip and works ok in less than 10 files, but crashes if files are more than 10.

Is their any way to do this without zipping it in the server side?.

Answer (score 0):

"ZIP64 files can be loaded, but only if the zip file is not "too big"

source [JSZip - GitHub](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/limitations.html)

Also check the [issues](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/48)